# Problem using ccTouchesEnded/ccTouchesBegan to move sprite in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d, cocos2d-x

I'm using ccTouchesBegan/ccTouchesEnded to move sprite from one point to another but I'm having problem, if i give two or more consecutive inputs one by one while sprite is moving(runAction is being performed). It first moves to last point i touched and then teleports itself to previous touched points one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect mulitouch use ccTouchesBegan as described in [tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_4_-_How_to_Fire_some_Bullets) at cocos2d-x site.
To detect single-touch you can use ccTouchBegan as described [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/7558?r=7595#message-7595).

Answer (score 1):

It does it because you are running two actions at the same time. Before making the sprite take an action just make it stop current/all actions he's doing.

Comment: What's the difference between CCTouchBegan and CCTouchesBegan?

Comment: I don't rwally know but I would say Touches tracks multitap? Look at the function methods and you will know.

Comment: @Beast one only invokes when working with multi-touch, and one will invoke with both single touch an multi-touch.

Comment: Can't get CCTouchBegan to work.